# How to edit configuration file Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-loki

I install `garafana/loki` with helm , now I want to change some configuration file , how can i edit it ? for example increase `log` store size and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Generally with helm charts you have a documentation which explains and details all the configurations that you can update.
If there's no documentation, go into the code and check if you find a {{ .Values.xxx }}. The "xxx" will be the name of the config to use to update the value.

So you can add these values in the `values.yaml` file or add it directly in the command line `--set livenessProbe.exec.command=[cat,docroot/CHANGELOG.txt]`. (if you want you can create your own yaml file and pass as parameter too...)

If the value you want seems to be fixed and you can't update it, download the chart, do your update and use it instead of the other one.
And for a project open source, you can open a Pull Request with your update to let other people use it too.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks  , i see loki conf fule located in promotion.yaml , how can i edit it? when i enter in pods i see it in /etc/loki/..yaml

Comment: About which file are you talking about?

For example, here is an example of `values.yaml` file where you can update informations to customize the deployment : https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/production/helm/loki/values.yaml